# Network Service Discovery, multiple network services from one phone?

Tags: java, android

I've been following [this article](http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd.html) and have managed to implement a basic verison of it.

What I wanted to ask is, can the same phone create multiple network services and then search those created services for a particular one?

Cheers